# Где найти подробный справочник функций шейдеров OpenGL?

Tags: справка, opengl

Максимум, что удалось откопать - это спецификация на английском языке, которая к тому же не является полной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, следует начать со спецификации. Действительно, она очень кратко описывает встроенные функции. Функции, требуемые стандартом. Начинайте читать начиная с раздела 8.

[OpenGL Shading Language Specification v4.20.6](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.20.6.clean.pdf)

Есть отличная книжа на русском. Она, разумеется, не может описать всё, но посиывает основное. Поможет начать. Надо сказать, я удивлён, что она ещё в продаже.

[Разработка и отладка шейдеров](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2619774/)

Обратите внимание также на [викию](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Category:GLSL_Programming). Много маленьких полезных примеров. Кирпичики из которых многое можно собрать.

И да, вы действительно правы: вопрос освещён очень плохо. Документации толком нет.

Comment: Вам что-нибудь известно об этой книжке  OpenGL4.0グラフィックシステム [単行本]  которую можно увидеть на официальном сайте OpenGL. Английский перевод имеется?

Comment: Её написали авторы первоначальной версии OpenGL. Но, по неизвестной причине, перевода на инглиш нигде нет.. похоже, вам придётся учить японский, чтобы прочесть ИМЕННО ЭТУ книгу :)

Comment: Или задействовать Google-переводчик. Только наверняка там какая-нибудь муть получится, как с английским. Особенно тему программирования переводчик плохо переводит.

Comment: Только сначала надо её найти. Эта книга не лежит в свободном доступе. Переводится всё это дело плохо, но исходный код приводимый в книге может пригодиться. Он всё равно на английском.

Answer (score 0):

Рост - OpenGL Трехмерная графика и язык программирования шейдеров